# Wordpress loading very slow on MAMP Pro

Tags: localhost, local-installation

I've just installed MAMP and MAMP Pro on my  Mac system and my Wordpress install is running extremely slow on MAMP Pro (much slower than it would on a remote server).

The actual content of the site is loading fast - it's only when I try to access any backend content that everything slows down to a crawl.

Any input on the potential reasons for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local web server being slow is something that bugs me as well. Some tips might help:

I think it is all about the database.

1. Check that you connect to the correct MySQL port (8889 is default). Even though 3306 (MySQL default) might work, changing to the "correct" gave me a boost.
2. In addition, you can try to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. You might need to check "Allow network access to MySQL" within the MAMP PRO MySQL config.

These settings helped me, though I am not completely happy with the response time.